# Deploy DRF API with VueJS frontend project

Tags: django, vue.js, deployment, digital-ocean

I'm trying to figure out how to deploy Django project (DRF API) with VueJS project.

```
/django_project/
/django_project/django_project/settings.py # +other stuff
/django_project/frontend/ # the VueJS project
/django_project/frontend/dist/ # the directory created by `npm run build`
```

I want to deploy it on `DigitalOcean apps` so it needs to act (probably) as a `Django` project because there is no space for setting up another server.

The goal is an ability to deploy project after every `git push`.

I was thinking about adding one (and only except `API` views) view that serves `index.html` file from `VueJS` project but I'm not sure how to make it work "automatically" so the app server will just do `collectstatic` to make everything work properly (eg. both `VueJS` frontend project and `Django` backend project).